# how to highlight search results

Tags: php, mysql, html, function, syntax-highlighting

hello i have a search function in that i will search a db for keywords. i would like to highlight the keywords and found a second function that i would like to implement into my search function.

so i have this code for the search:

```
<?php 
function searchText($keywords){
    global $db;
    $returned_results = array();
    $where2 = "";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords); 
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);

    foreach ($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
        $where2 .= "`column` LIKE '%$keyword%'";

        if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1)){ 
            $where2 .= " OR ";
        }
    }

    $results_text = "SELECT `a`, `b`, LEFT(`c`, 150) as `c` FROM `table` WHERE $where2"; 
    $results_num_text = ($query2 = mysqli_query($db, $results_text)) ? mysqli_num_rows($query2) : 0; 
    if ($results_num_text === 0){
        return false;
    } else {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){

            $returned_results[] = array(
                'ab' => $row['ab'],
                'cd' => $row['cd'], 
            );
        }

        return $returned_results;
    }
}
?>
```

and would like to implement a second function into it:

```
<?php
function mark_words ($text, $words, $colors = false)
{

    if (!$colors || !is_array($colors) ) {
        $colors = array('#ff9999', '#ffff99', '#ff99ff', '#99ffff','#99ff99');
    }

    $c = 0;

    foreach ($words as $w) {

        $w = preg_quote(trim($w));

        if($w=='') {
            continue;
        }

        $regexp = "/($w)(?![^<]+>)/i";

        $replacement = '<b style="background-color:'.$colors[$c].'">\\1</b>';

        $text = preg_replace ($regexp,$replacement ,$text);

        $c++;
        if ($c >= count($colors)) {
            $c=0;
        }
    }
    return $text;
}

$example = <<< EOT
some text is here inside
EOT;

$search = array('some','is', 'inside');

echo mark_words($example, $search);
?>
```

so i have this code that doesnt work:

```
<?php 
function searchText($keywords, $colors = false){
    global $db;

     if (!$colors || !is_array($colors) ) {
        $colors = array('#ff9999', '#ffff99', '#ff99ff', '#99ffff','#99ff99');
    }

    $c = 0;

    $returned_results = array();
    $where2 = "";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords); 
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);

    foreach ($keywords as $key=>$keyword){

    $regexp = "/($w)(?![^<]+>)/i";
        $replacement = '<b style="background-color:'.$colors[$c].'">\\1</b>';

        $text = preg_replace($regexp,$replacement ,$keywords);
        $c++;

        if ($c >= count($colors)) {
            $c=0;
        }

        $where2 .= "`b` LIKE '%$keyword%'";

        if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1)){ 
            $where2 .= " OR ";
        }
    }

    $results_text = "SELECT `a`, LEFT(`b`, 150) as `b`, `c` FROM `table` WHERE $where2";
    $results_num_text = ($query2 = mysqli_query($db, $results_text)) ? mysqli_num_rows($query2) : 0; 
    if ($results_num_text === 0){
        return false;
    } else {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){

            $returned_results[] = array(
                'ab' => $row['a'],
                'cd' => $row['b'],
            );
        }

        return $returned_results;
        $highlight = array($keywords);
        echo mark_words($highlight);
    }
}
?>
```

as i looked for it how to do so i found two possibilities. the first would be a function the second would be directly to highlight it from the select query:

```
SELECT
        REPLACE(`col`, 'foobar', '<span class="highlight">foobar</span>') AS `formated_foobar`
  FROM
        …
  WHERE
        `col` LIKE "%foobar%"
```

so my question is how can i implement the second function into the search function or would it be better to use the second method?

if there is someone who could help me i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: your `\\1` will literally print `\1`. To use the stored value, you need `\1` or `$1`

Comment: hello, that still doesnt work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't make it too hard for yourself. All you need it to replace every occurrence of a word with the word wrapped in the span with the required style applied. This should work for you:

```
function highlight_word( $content, $word, $color ) {
    $replace = '<span style="background-color: ' . $color . ';">' . $word . '</span>'; // create replacement
    $content = str_replace( $word, $replace, $content ); // replace content

    return $content; // return highlighted data
}

function highlight_words( $content, $words, $colors ) {
    $color_index = 0; // index of color (assuming it's an array)

    // loop through words
    foreach( $words as $word ) {
        $content = highlight_word( $content, $word, $colors[$color_index] ); // highlight word
        $color_index = ( $color_index + 1 ) % count( $colors ); // get next color index
    }

    return $content; // return highlighted data
}



// words to find
$words = array(
    'normal',
    'text'
);

// colors to use
$colors = array(
    '#88ccff',
    '#cc88ff'
);

// faking your results_text
$results_text = array(
    array(
        'ab'    => 'AB #1',
        'cd'    => 'Some normal text with normal words isn\'t abnormal at all'
    ), array(
        'ab'    => 'AB #2',
        'cd'    => 'This is another text containing very normal content'
    )
);

// loop through results (assuming $output1 is true)
foreach( $results_text as $result ) {
    $result['cd'] = highlight_words( $result['cd'], $words, $colors );

    echo '<fieldset><p>ab: ' . $result['ab'] . '<br />cd: ' . $result['cd'] . '</p></fieldset>';
}
```

Using Regular Expressions to replace content would do as well, though using `str_replace()` is a bit faster.

The functions accepts these arguments:

`highlight_word( string, string, string );`

`highlight_words( string, array, array );`

The above example results in:

[image]

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. i understand this but dont know how i can implement this to a returned result array that will be echoed by if ($output1 == true){
 foreach ($results_text as $result){
   
  echo "<fieldset><p>"
  ."ab:".$result['ab']."<br>"
  ."cd: ".$result['cd']."<br>"} and in cd should be the highlighted keywords.

Comment: If you are using spans, please use classes and not hardcoding the values like that ;)

Comment: i`m having problems understanding $results_text. i get it that way, that the arrays inside will be the arrays that comes from the search function, or? so i cant say how many arrays there will be in. so it actually is: $results_text = (searchText($keywords)) but how can i get the specific array key 'ab' in that to highlight just this?

Comment: using $results_text = array(searchText($keywords)); echoes the error message: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in...

Comment: You should use `$results_text = searchText( $keywords );` After that you can use my foreach loop. `foreach( $results_text as $result )` etc...

Comment: i simply left $result_text and it works. so i found out, thats already given after if (empty($errors)). thank you very much for your help. have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

By using str_ireplace instead of str_replace, the function will work case insensitive

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the SQL method. As time goes on, and you have more and more highlighting rules, that will become unmanageable. Also trickier to handle the cases where you need to highlight `foo` differently to `foobar`, but one contains the other.

Separate your data handling from your formatting.